# how can I save a msg to a file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to save a trajectory_msgs. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58112/how-can-i-save-a-msg-to-a-file/) by [RosRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4422/rosros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to save a particular text message directly to a file you can do

```
rostopic echo -p /your_topic/goes/here > /path/to/your/file
```

you won't see any ouptut here, but in your file you'll see the message in a CSV format.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just record the topic using [rosbag](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag).

Then replay the message(s) or analyze them off-line using rxbag or the rosbag API.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3